# Production Application Error Reporting for Errors on the Client Side

Tags: angularjs, node.js, error-reporting

I have an AngularJS client side application that converts things to YouTube. There is an error occurring when trying to create a playlist on iPhones. I can log YouTube's response to the browser's console, but that doesn't help me since I can't see it. Is there a way to send that client side error to the developer? Is there a good error reporting service I can use? Thanks. My app runs node.js on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plug in the ios device to your computer, with safari then you can debug more easily

http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/